# Zero set of polynomial and loops

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Let $p(z)=\Re(p)+i \Im(p)$ be a non-constant (analytic) polynomial and consider the algebraic sets $Z_1=\{z\in\mathbb C:\Re(p)=0\}$ and $Z_2=\{z\in\mathbb C:\Im(p)=0\}$.

Can $Z_1\cup Z_2$ contain [loops](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology))?

Comment: If $p$ is the zero polynomial, then $Z_{1} \cup Z_{2}$ is the domain of $p$, which certainly contains "loops" with the usual meaning. If that's not what you had in mind, could you please add the relevant conditions on $p$ (Is $p$ non-constant? Is the domain a complex Euclidean space? Etc.) and/or the definition of "loops"? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region inside such a loop would be a nonempty bounded connected open set $R$ with  $\partial R \subseteq Z_1 \cup Z_2$.
Then $p(R)$ is a bounded region, and (by the Open Mapping Theorem) $\partial p(R) \subseteq p(\partial R)$ which is contained in the union of the real and imaginary axes.  But the  axes do not contain the boundary of any bounded region of $\mathbb C$.  Therefore no such $R$ exists.

EDIT: This generalizes to any nonconstant entire function $p$  and any closed set $K \subset \mathbb C$ such that the complement $K^c$ has no bounded connected component.
Then $(p^{-1}(K))^c$ also has no bounded connected component.